# fldtypes XSL reference of available variables?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, xslt

I've been using the $List variable but now am looking for one that will give me an identifier I can use to get the current subsite off of the root, does anyone know a good resource where I can find what variables are available to me in the fldtypes*.xsl file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked the question too quick.  Just found it,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806158.aspx